# RavenDB Index on SubClasses

Tags: ravendb

I am trying to create an indexes for ProviderProfileId, Email, and Address1

I have created queries that work, but not indexes.  I know the inheriting from List for the collections might be part of the problem.  List is a carry over from when I had to do a significant amount of XmlSerialization on much older projects, and became a habit in my modeling.  I also noticed that in Raven the serialization is much cleaner that if AddressCollection were just List.  Any thoughts?

Model is similar to

```
public class Customer {
   public string Id {get;set}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public AddressCollection {get;set;}
   public SocialMediaAliasCollection {get;set;}
}

public class SocialMediaAliasCollection:List<SocialMedialProfile>{}

public class SocialMediaProfile{
    public string ProviderProfileId {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
}

public class AddressCollection:List<Address>{}

public class Address{
 public string Address {get;set;}
 public string City {get;set;}
 public string State {get;set;}
 public string Zip {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Btw, both collection-types "SocialMediaAliasCollection" and "AddressCollection" don't add value. I recommend to remove them for simplicity.

Comment: For the most part your are right they don't add much value, but in many cases when working with legacy systems this approach gives you better control of the XmlSerialization process, which we have to do in many other parts of our application. What would you suggest IEnumerable<Address> AddressCollection {get;set;} ?  Would that solve the index creation issue?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest IEnumerable<Address> or IList<Address> instead. Not just that it makes Json serialization cleaner but also your code. However, I don't know if it solves your issues, since I don't know WHAT are your issues. What is the question? How did you try tro create an index and how does it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now answered it, basically I didn't know linq well enough.  Makes sense once I figured it out.  I was trying to make an index for a sub collection, in this case addresses. Not 100% this works, but it does compile and when I push the index to the server it does not blow up.

```
Map = collection => from item in collection where item.AddressCollection != null
                    from item2 in item.AddressCollection
                    select new {
                         item2.city
                     }
```